# Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V

Tags: java, spring, solr, apache-kafka

Basically, I need to index and query data from Solr. So first, I am trying to create a HttpSolrClient and facing problems with that. The dependencies added in the project are:

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Edgware.SR5</spring-cloud.version>
    <spring-kafka.version>1.3.8.RELEASE</spring-kafka.version>
    <curator-test-version>2.12.0</curator-test-version>
    <solr.version>7.5.0</solr.version>
    <zk.version>3.4.10</zk.version>
    <curator-version>4.0.0</curator-version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.7</slf4j.version>
    <commons-lang3.version>3.5</commons-lang3.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20171018</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
        <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.2</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
        <artifactId>avro-tools</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.2</version>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
        <artifactId>avro-compiler</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
        <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>tech.allegro.schema.json2avro</groupId>
        <artifactId>converter</artifactId>
        <version>0.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
        <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
        <version>${solr.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
        <artifactId>solr-core</artifactId>
        <version>${solr.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.curator</groupId>
                <artifactId>curator-framework</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
                <artifactId>metrics-jetty9</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
        <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
        <version>${zk.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.curator</groupId>
        <artifactId>curator-recipes</artifactId>
        <version>${curator-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
                <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.curator</groupId>
        <artifactId>curator-client</artifactId>
        <version>${curator-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.curator</groupId>
        <artifactId>curator-test</artifactId>
        <version>${curator-test-version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
                <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-lang3.version}</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>

        </dependency>



    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
            <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>none</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>schema</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/avro/</sourceDirectory>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>8</source>
                <target>8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>


    </plugins>
</build>
```

Ran the maven dependency tree. 
Results below: 
mvn dependency:tree | grep solr
[INFO] +- org.apache.solr:solr-core:jar:7.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.solr:solr-solrj:jar:7.5.0:compile

In the repository, the solr folder has only 3 sub folders. 1. solr-core, 2. solr-parent, 3. solr-solrj

Tried running mvn in debug mode. 
mvnDebug clean install -X 
Getting the below error information:

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

An attempt was made to call the method org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.(Ljava/lang/String;)V but it does not exist. Its class, org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient, is available from the following locations:

```
jar:file:/Users/admin/.m2/repository/org/apache/solr/solr-solrj/7.5.0/solr-solrj-7.5.0.jar!/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/HttpSolrClient.class
```

It was loaded from the following location:

```
file:/Users/admin/.m2/repository/org/apache/solr/solr-solrj/7.5.0/solr-solrj-7.5.0.jar
```

Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'solrClient' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/solr/SolrAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient]: Factory method 'solrClient' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.(Ljava/lang/String;)V

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient]: Factory method 'solrClient' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.(Ljava/lang/String;)V

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.(Ljava/lang/String;)V

```
private HttpSolrClient solrClient;

public SolrJavaIntegration(String clientUrl) {
    solrClient = new HttpSolrClient.Builder(clientUrl).build();
}
```

need to be able to create a HttpSolrClient without any issues but having problem with that.

Answer (score 1):

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = SolrAutoConfiguration.class)
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

disable **SolrAutoConfiguration**, it might work